# regex python match different zipcode for different countries

Tags: python, regex, flask, flask-restful

I have a question about python regex.
I am trying to make a register page with flask-restful and I am struggling with matching the zipcodes to different countries. E.g zipcode Netherlands: 1234AB, zipcode Belgium: 1234.
What I want: if Netherlands is the chosen country, the zipcode has to have 4 digits and 2 characters.
if Belgium is the chosen country, the zipcode has to have only 4 digits.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("db/webshop.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        split_string = args['email'].split("@",1)
        substring = split_string[0]
        if len(args['password']) < 8:
            print("Make sure your password is at least 8 letters")
            return
        elif re.search('[0-9]',args['password']) is None:
            print("Make sure your password has a number in it")
            return
        elif re.search('[A-Z]',args['password']) is None: 
            print("Make sure your password has a capital letter in it")
            return
        elif len(substring) <= 5:
            print("Make sure your email has 5 letter in it")
            return
        elif args['email'].find('@')==-1:
            print("Make sure your email has @ letter in it")
            return
        elif args['email'].find('.')==-1:
            print("Make sure your email has . letter in it")
            return
        elif args['country'] == '1':
            if re.match(r'\d[0-9]{4}', args['zipcode']):
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (email,password,firstname,infix,lastname,street,housenumber,zipcode,city,newsletter,userrole_id,country_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (args['email'],args['password'],args['firstname'],args['infix'],args['lastname'],args['street'],args['housenumber'],args['zipcode'],args['city'],args['newsletter'],'1',args['country']))
                con.commit()
            else:
                print("zipcode is not matching with given arguments")
                return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
belgium = '1' # assuming that belgium is '1'

if args['country'] == belgium:
  zip_code_regexp = "^[0-9]{4}$"
else:
  zip_code_regexp = "^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$"


if re.match(zip_code_regexp, args['zipcode']):
  # ...
else:
  # ...
```

Comment: WOW idriss, thank you so much.  I only used this part "^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$". but I am wondering. What does the '^' stand for?

Comment: @Abdullah It means "start with". You can use any decent online regexp evaluator to have a better understanding. For example: https://regex101.com/r/XOwnyY/1/

Comment: thanks mate, but i have stumbled accros another obstacle. Now i want to get the args['housnumber'] to only have digits. e.g OK:123 NOT OK:123asfv.